# Windows - AssignProcessToJobObject ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED on Second Attempt

Tags: c++, windows, shell, process

I have a running application that is trying to run a child process -- in this specific example, it's an FFMPEG process to perform video captures for my app. The **child process must be automatically killed** in case my app abruptly crashes. **Windows Job Objects** was the answer based on some stackoverflow questions and [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects).

In my first attempt, whenever I launched the process, I created the job object, then launched the process, and assigned it. When I terminate the process, I also terminate the job object and close the handle. But when I enter the function a second time, I find that my job object is still valid when doing `OpenJobObject` -- despite previously closing the only handle I have to it. This led me to create the job object **once**, then assign new processes to it. The idea being, I need to be able to start and stop recordings multiple times in a session.

Not showing any error handling in snippets below for brevity:

```
void Initialize()
{
    HANDLE hJob = CreateJobObject(NULL, "recordingJob");
    JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION jobLimitInfo = { 0 };

    // Kill On Job Close is the flag needed to automatically kill the child process
    jobLimitInfo.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags = JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;
    if (!SetInformationJobObject(hJob, JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, &jobLimitInfo, sizeof(jobLimitInfo)))
    {
        // Error...
    }
}
```

Assume `Initialize()` was called prior to this. `Launch/TerminateRecordingProcess` can be called multiple times per session -- obviously paired together.

```
void LaunchRecordingProcess()
{
    // 1. Prep commandline args
    // 2. ShellExec
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO shellInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&shellInfo, sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO));
    shellInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    shellInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    shellInfo.hwnd = 0;
    shellInfo.lpFile = exePath;
    shellInfo.lpParameters = commandLine;
    shellInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
    shellInfo.nShow = SW_HIDE;
    shellInfo.lpVerb = nullptr;

    ShellExecuteEx(&shellInfo);

    // 3. Store the process handle to be able to stop it later
    m_processHandle = shellInfo.hProcess;
    
    // 4. Job object is already created, open it and assign the process to it
    HANDLE hJob = OpenJobObject(JOB_OBJECT_ALL_ACCESS, false, "recordingJob");
    if(!AssignProcessToJobObject(hJob, shellInfo.hProcess))
    {
        // Get error -- this is where my issue occurs
    }
}

void TerminateRecordingProcess()
{
    if (m_processHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (TerminateProcess(m_processHandle , 0))
        {
            // 5 s timeout; use INFINITE for no timeout
            const DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(m_processHandle , 5000);
            // error handling...
        }
        else
        {
            // error
        }

        CloseHandle(m_processHandle );
        m_processHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
}
```

**Problem**: When the above code runs the first time, it works like a charm. Recording starts and stops, with the process being killed off the task manager. When triggered a second time, `AssignProcessToJobObject` always **fail with error code 5 -- ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED**. Existing answers to this problem are varied -- some suggest a problem using the debugger, but this isn't the case here. Others suggest a Job Object should not be recycled (but that was more or less my first failed approach). The documentation doesn't stipulate any further rules on why this can go wrong, nor does it impose any related rules on how a job object can be reused, recreated, and assigned to. Any idea how to troubleshoot?